# Grails Resources Plugin Assertion Failed

Tags: grails, resources

We deployed an very basic Grails-Application (Grails 2.2.2) on several servers and many times we get an error in during the startup:

```
013-06-22 11:45:45,686 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: Assertion failed: 

assert f.delete()
       | |
       | false
   /usr/local/tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/_/grails-resources/js/application.js

at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:97)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1082)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1106)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:906)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:412)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPlugin.doWithDynamicMethods(DefaultGrailsPlugin.java:703)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager.doDynamicMethods(DefaultGrailsPluginManager.java:741)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.configure(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:174)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.configure(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:127)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsConfigUtils.configureWebApplicationContext(GrailsConfigUtils.java:121)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoader.java:107)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:618)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:963)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1600)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

We did not do any complex things, neither modified any configs of this. It came up the first time after we changed the URL mappings to

```
class UrlMappings {

static mappings = {
    "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
        constraints {
            // apply constraints here
        }
    }

    "/"(controller:'analyse')
    "500"(view:'/error')
}
}
```

War creation works 100%, deployment on Tomcat 6 works 10%. Running the development mode via `grails run-app` works 100%.

Any suggestions/ideas is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had kind of the same issue.

The problem was with the permissions of the folders... Go to  /usr/local/tomcat/work/Catalina/ and look for the read and write permissions of your user.

We had them with owner root... we put them with the correct owner and it got solved.

regards

Gil